# Security proof for multi-message signature scheme

Tags: signature

I have been going over the proof for security of a multi-message signature scheme and have a question. The part of the proof that I am unsure about is marked in yellow in the bellow snapshot. I do not understand why it is true.

Also, the attacker A' (as defined in the proof seen below) usually calls an oracle t times, but seeing as we have only one access to the oracle for A' does that mean A' has access to the multi-message scheme Sign() function? Does that not break the whole point of this? Can we not just call that Sign function on some message and be done with it?

This is the proof I have been presented with, (taken from [here](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~canetti/f08-materials/scribe8.pdf)):

> [image: 1/2]
>   [image: 2/2]

Comment: 1) *Also, the attacker A' (as defined in the proof seen below) usually calls an oracle t times*
q(n), you mean?
2) *but seeing as we have only one access to the oracle for A' does that mean A' has access to the multi-message scheme Sign() function?*
That's not necessarily true: the *reduction* (A here) usually can run the *adversary* (A' here) multiple times (if required on related input, randomness...)
3)*Can **we** not just call that Sign function on some message and be done with it?*
Which actor are you referring to?

Comment: By we I mean A. 
We want A to give us a message and a valid signature for it. To do that it may use A'. 
But A' is only useful if it has its oracle calls which we cannot grant it seeing as we only have one such call in the case of the reduction (A). 
This leads me to assume that A' is capable of giving A the oracle replies itself (by access to sign or whatever). But if A can do that then why does it need A' at all? Why not just choose some message and sign it?

Comment: *This forgery must include a forgery of one of the underlying one-time signatures.*
Intuitively, the reduction (A) guess the point *i* at which the adversary (A') is going to forge, and "embeds" its own challenge at that point by appending *v* to the previous signature. If A' does indeed produce a  forgery *s* at *i*, then *s* itself is a valid forgery for the OTS.

Comment: Yes, the idea is for *A* to generate *the rest of* the public-key, secret-key pairs by itself --- only the secret key that corresponds to the challenge public key *v* (the one embedded) is unknown to *A* (and it hopes that *A'* forges at that point).

Comment: I see, I think I understand. I will mull it over some more. Thank you.